# Preg replace em links textarea

Tags: php

O que eu posso fazer para jogar estes link no `textarea`

Ex:

```
http://link1.com/embed/código/nomepagina 
http://link2.com/v/código/nomepagina 
http://link3.com/e/código/
```

E ele me retornar somente

```
http://link1.com/código/ 
http://link2.com/código/ 
http://link3.com/código/
```

Pegando o código somente e formatando deixando da forma a cima.

Comment: Rogério voce quer pular uma linha no textarea é isso ? ou quer mudar o formato ?

Comment: Os links quando é gerado, é formado do jeito do primeiro exemplo, eu queria conseguir formatar esses 3 links e deixar do jeito do segundo, pegar a parte CODIGO de cada link e a parte link1,link2,link3

Comment: Não duplique suas perguntas. Se a [anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/372921/112052) não foi bem recebida, concentre seus esforços lá. Edite-a para que fique dentro do escopo, leia mais na [help/on-topic] e na página [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criei esse regex que atende neste caso que você fez:

```
(http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/)(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(.+)?

 ^ .... grupo do link        ^.... grupo do código
```

Depois pega os elementos de cada grupo que será usado e junta.

Ficaria assim o código:

```
$str = "http://link1.com/embed/codigo/nomepagina 
        http://link2.com/v/codigo/nomepagina 
        http://link3.com/e/codigo/";

$str = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/\w+\.\w+\/)(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(.+)?/', '$1$3 ', $str);
                  //                                              ^ aqui haverá a junção
```

Saída:

```
http://link1.com/codigo http://link2.com/codigo http://link3.com/codigo
```

Como é uma url eu retirei do `código` o acento no `ó`

**Edição**

Para subdomínios e outros tipos de domínios fiz o código assim:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?([\w\.]+\/)([\w-_]+\/)?([\w-_]+)\/?(.+)?/', '$2$4 ', $str);
```

Comment: funcionou até ai, mas e se uns links tiver subdominio e outros não? como funcionaria? tipo os dois primeiros for subdominio.link1.com/embed/codigo/... e os outros sem ?

Comment: @RogérioSilva vou fazer para subdominions

Comment: @RogérioSilva está lá

Comment: @RogérioSilva deu certo?

Comment: sim obrigado!!!

Comment: Andrei, sabe pq quando o link tem - (traço) não pega? ex: site.com/embed/hB8l23wOU-E/ ele retorna somente hB8l23wOU

Comment: @RogérioSilva vou fazer uma edição

Comment: @RogérioSilva está lá!